# How to retrieve sales order number when we make copy of existing sales order and display in new field in suitescripting

Tags: suitescript2.0

I create one empty field on sales order, when i make copy of that existing sales order then I want the previous sales order number on that copy. How to do that in suite script 2.0 please help me.

Answer (score 0):

When copying a record, the `id` parameter in the URL has the internal ID of the sales order it is being copied from. So, you should be able to do this as follows:

1. Create a User Event script with a beforeLoad function, and deploy it to the Sales Order record with Event Type of Copy.
2. In the script, load the Sales Order record with ID `scriptContext.request.parameters.id`, and copy its `tranid` field into the custom field you have created.

Comment: can you please elaborate or is it possible to share that particular code

Comment: The value got applied on the original sales order, not the new copy